# LI Background Images (.PNG) not appeared in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I am using the following CSS but it never  shows background images in IE6. But if I remove the filter .. AlphaLoader command, then it shows with grey background.

Here is my CSS Code

```
.fg-block1 ul, .fg-block3 ul
{
 list-style:none;
 }
.fg-block1 ul li, .fg-block3 ul li
{
 padding-left:28px;
 background:url(images/bullet-2.png) no-repeat left top;
 font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:11px;
 border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
 text-align:left;
 background-position:1px 0;
 line-height:16px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
}
.fg-block3 ul li
{
 border-bottom:none;
}
.fg-block1 ul li a, .fg-block3 ul li a
{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.fg-block1 ul li a:hover, .fg-block3 ul li a:hover
{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this :

http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/

Answer (score 0):

[AlphaImageLoader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969(VS.85).aspx) hack works only if you set dimensions to the parent container where you load your png as a background.

If you add `width` and `height` and `display:block` to your `<li>`'s it should be fine. Otherwise - consider different approach.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend jQuery png fix. see links below

[jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iepngfix)

[another source](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/)

Answer (score 0):

I never tried the jQuery plugin, but after dealing with a lot of PNG problems in IE6 the best fix I found is by far [DD Belated PNG fix](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/). The TwinHelix fix mentioned before presented some problems for me in certain scenarios.